# How I can insert SQL statements with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

Student :

```
studentid | fname | lname | add | dob
---------------------------------------------------------
 01       | A     | a     | x   | 01/01/1997
 02       | B     | b     | y   | 02/02/1995
 03       | C     | c     | z   | 03/03/1993
```

Course:

```
courseid | name | prerequisites
-------------------------------
IPG      | ipg  |  NULL 
PPL      | ppl  | IPG
SEG      | seg  | PPL
```

Enrolment:

```
student | course | semester | finalgrade
-----------------------------------------
01      | IPG    | 1        | G
02      | PPL    | 2        | E
03      | PPL    | 2        | F
```

How I can enroll student 01 in course PPL by validating the prerequisites in course table??

Student must enroll course IPG before he/she enroll in PPL course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into enrolment (student, course) 
            select 01,'IPG' from enrolment where student=01 
            and course = (select prerequisites from course where courseid ='IPG');
```

Can you try the combination or insert and select.